# Есть ли способ узнать статус пользователя на локальной машине?

Tags: c#, windows

На локальной машине может быть много пользователей, при этом несколько из них могут "произвести вход", но активен будет только один из них (тот кто сейчас и работает за компьютером). Так вот вопрос, могу ли я из кода узнать текущий пользователь сейчас активен или нет? У меня программ работает в трее и периодически задаёт вопрос на который пользователь должен ответить, но нужно знать с какой учёткой в данный момент работают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, нет такого понятия — «текущий активный пользователь». Windows является многопользовательской системой, в ней могут одновременно быть активными несколько logon-сессий.

Вот древняя статья Реймонда Чена об этом: [Who says there’s only one? There can be more than one logon session](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060822-00/?p=30013).

Примеры оттуда:

- Terminal Services означает удалённые логины, при этом на физической машине может и не быть логина (да что там, может и не быть монитора).
- Media Center Extender даёт возможность другому пользователю смотреть кино в другой комнате.

---

Показывайте вопрос *всем* пользователям, при неактивности убирайте его через некоторое время.

Comment: может я недопонял вопроса. А как можно показать всем пользователям? Если программа запущена из под какого-то конкретного пользователя?

Comment: @koks_rs, если это сервис

Comment: Это же только для серверной версии Windows? В обычной не более одного и, возможно, remote assistant.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А ты глянь статью по ссылке. Media Center Extender никто не отменял. Нету у винды такого внутреннего понятия — «активный пользователь».

Comment: @koks_rs: Ну ТС вроде пишет «На локальной машине может быть много пользователей» — так что вопрос не о той учётке, под которой бежит программа, а о всех возможных. Можно положить программу в автозагрузку для каждого из пользователей, тогда будет в каждой сессии бежать по экземпляру.

Comment: @VladD,  но я ведь я правильно понял что экзмепляр запущенный из под одной сессии не может ничего знать про свой другой экземпляр в другой сессии? Но  если это сервис, разве можно создать один сервис, который будет в одном экземпляре для всех пользователей?

Comment: @VladD, в диспетчере задач на вкладке Users есть колонка Status. Как до этого значения добраться?

Comment: @koks_rs: Ну, почему, они могут договориться. Например, может бежать центральный сервис из-под привилегированной учётки, и служить в качестве хаба для обменом информацией.

Comment: @Qwertiy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379437%28VS.85%29.aspx, по идее.

Comment: @VladD, [tag:C#] ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy: P/Invoke никто не отменял :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Или через WMI, наверное проще будет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @VladD, неужели в шарпе, предназначенном и для UI (winforms, wpf), и для сервисов (WCF) нет встроенной функциональности на эту тему?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Думаю, что нет. Существование вообще юзеров за пределами текущего — подробность реализации ОС, UI-фреймворк не должен быть за это ответственен.

Comment: @VladD, но сервис-то может быть от System и пользователи могут быть ему интересны.

Comment: @koks_rs всё верно, программа работает под автораном и могут быть запущены одновременно у нескольких пользователей, но показать сообщение нужно только "активному"

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, но это глубокая системная штука. C# всё же язык, не привязанный к одной системе настолько. Ну и для всего WinAPI делать управляемую обёртку долго, дорого и никому в пределах экспериментальной погрешности не нужно. (А кому реально надо, возьмут P/Invoke.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated;
```

[WindowsIdentity.IsAuthenticated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.isauthenticated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: нет это не работает. для проверки я написал небольшой код. смысл кода это создать файл в той же папке где и сама программа и записать туда значение IsAuthenticated, после чего запустил этот код и перелогинился на другого пользователя, значение всегда равно true

Comment: сам код: string path = "MyTest.txt";System.Timers.Timer timerCurUser = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);timerCurUser.Elapsed += (sender, argsForTime) =>
 {
 bool isAus = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated;
  if (!File.Exists(path))
 using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
  {
   Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(isAus.ToString());
   fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
   }
   else
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true))
   {
       file.WriteLine(isAus.ToString());
    }
 };
timerCurUser.Start();